# Maven and Ant test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, junit

I am trying to compile a project using Ant script. It is a Maven project. When I use pom.xml all the things work fine. In total, it generates 1040 .class files. When I try to run the project using Ant, it generates 1066 files. However, when I try to run junit test-cases from Ant script, it produces some weird errors.

Question:
1 - Why Ant script generates more .class files than Maven?
2 - Why the test-cases are generating errors?

Why I want to do this:
I need to run a third party tool on this project and that tool requires Ant script with some specific modifications.

Excerpt of Ant script

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile main code">
   <mkdir dir="${build.classes}" />
   <javac  target="1.6"
     source="1.6"
     srcdir="${source.java}"
     destdir="${build.classes}" 
     debug="${compile.debug}" 
     deprecation="${compile.deprecation}" 
     optimize="${compile.optimize}">
    <classpath>
     <pathelement path="${build.classes}" />
     <pathelement path="${dep.classpath}" />
    </classpath>
   </javac>
</target>
```

Errors:
Some project specific errors such as cannot connect to some components.

### Update

I added the following Ant script in my compile target:

```
<copy todir="${build.classes}">
             <fileset dir="${source.java}">
               <include name="**/*"/>
               <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
               <exclude name="**/package.html"/>
             </fileset>
</copy>
```

Now I can build the project using Ant and all the test-cases also work with the .class generated by Ant. Is there any Java code that could do the same task?

Comment: The different classes may just be due to different dependency definitions between the `pom.xml` and the `build.xml`. Any clue there? Seemingly, different dependency definition can cause tests to fail, because of missing / different classes or libraries.

Comment: I double checked the dependencies. All the dependencies are same for both Maven and Ant.

Comment: As it is not the dependencies (i would byte-check them again) it could be nearly anything. As a example say your ANT build uses another version, configuration or tool to generate Webservice- Stubs or JAXB Models (generally appliable for anything generated) this would without a doubt soon lead to a different number of class-files produced/ generated. (When it comes to the test cases and your added ANT-Task it seems [assumptation!] that your tests were missing certain non-java-class files a.k.a. ressources which for Maven need to be placed in specific folders - or the folder must be configured)

Comment: try runing `mvn dependency:tree` to see what dependencies you have in your `pom.xml`. Compare them with your Ant (`build.xml`). Question: Do you generate some sources? Question: what plugins do you have in your `pom.xml`?